# How to introduce an idea before stating it?

Tags: colons, compound-sentences

This one always gets me. How do I introduce an idea and then state it in the same sentence? Does it simply require a colon?

> That's because we have one goal: for you to consider your website a
>   success.

Comment: A dash works too, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous different ways to express ideas in a single sentence. Your use of a colon is perfectly fine, but here are a few other examples:

> - That is because the one goal we have is for you to consider your website a success.
> - That is because we only have one goal, which is for you to consider your website a success.
> - That is because we have one goal—for you to consider your website a success.

You can see that there are multiple ways to say what you're looking for, but in my opinion a colon works best if you want to emphasize the latter part of your sentence. It is the most clear one of these sentences, along with perhaps the sentence containing a dash. The other sentences seem to put less emphasis on what the goal is.

Comment: I tried rewording it a few times to get rid of the colon as well. I'm going to go with the dash, as it seems less formal. I mainly wanted to know if my use of the colon was correct, and I also believe it is. Thanks!

Comment: The one with "which " in it could use a comma before "which".